# 2D Array LinearSearch of Sorted List

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, netbeans

Ideally, I would like for the counter to stop once I find the value.  When I run the program, it continues to compare the other values in the matrix.

```
public static void LinearSearch1(int[][] matrix, int array_size, int target) {
        int row, col;
        int comparison_counter = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (!found)
        {
            for (row = 0; row < array_size; row++) 
            {

                for (col = 0; col < array_size; col++) 
                {
                    comparison_counter++;   
                    if (matrix[row][col] == target) 
                    {
                        found = true;

                    }//end if


                }//end inner for    
            }//end outer for
        } //end while

        System.out.println(target + " found in " + comparison_counter + " number of comparisons using linear search");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `break;` after the `found = true`, but it's going to exit all the loops. If you want to exit just the for loops, then you have to add `&& !found` into the for loop tests.

Btw, why do you have a `while(!found)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matrix[row][col] == target) 
{
    found = true;
    break; //Add this line
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If thee boolean variable **found** is set to `false` you are never coming in the while loop

it should be:

```
while (!found)
```

and once `found = true`  then add a `break`;